# Use dropzone.js inside an existing form in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I want to use Dropzone.js, but all tutorial I've found are exclusive upload forms.

I have found no doc with mixing image upload with user creation for example.

Am I in a wrong use case?

If not, how can I do it, I don't know how to pass uploaded file name?

How should I have a dedicated form to upload pic, and relation with my User creation in other form...

I'm really not sure how to do this!

Any idea would be appreciated!!!

Comment: The idea of Dropzone is to upload files asynchronously without the need to upload the whole form. I would not display the upload field (dropzone) when creating a new user. I would only make the user fill the necessary fields and after the "Create" button is clicked redirect to the recently created user's edit page where I will display the upload option. That way you could upload files asychronously using dropzone, just once the user is created.

Comment: I do it that way. But admin can add users, and he has the ability to enter all fields at once. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: In that case what you could do is to use the classical upload method using <input type="file" /> that's what comes to my mind

Comment: You could generate a token everytime you enter to the form that creates a new user, as Dropzone uploads asynchronously, all files you upload will be associated with no user but they can be associated with a token ;) and when you click create button to create the user, the token will also be sent as field of the form (hidden) and if there exist uploads with the same token then associate those uploads to the user you just created. That could be one solution